# how to reload a function from a module in python

Tags: python, reload

I have a function `myFunc(a,b)` defined in `myMod` under `MyFolder`.
I import the function and call the function in the following way, it works.

```
from MyFolder.myMod import myFunc
myFunc(a,b)
```

Now I update my function . I would like to reload my function, but `reload(myMod.myFunc)` does not work. `reload(MyFolder.myMod)` does not work either. May i know the reason?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I unload (reload) a Python module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437589/how-do-i-unload-reload-a-python-module)

Comment: Hi aydow. Actually, i read the post you mentioned before i posted my own. The post seems does not work for me. I can run my function 'myFunc(a,b)' successfully, but it gives an error 'name 'myFunc' is not defined' when i run 'reload('myFunc)'

Answer (score 0):

Modules are compiled **only** **once** when you import them. And when you change them, python won't pick them up unless re imported i.e recompiled. So to get around that you can do this

```
import importlib
importlib.reload(module_name)
```

for python 3.x

And for python 2.x you can

`reload(module_name)`